# What is the meaning of ord in ord() function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ord

ord() is used to get the ASCII value of the character we insert.

Like ***`ord("A")` => 65***

Does anyone know what **ord** stands for?

Is it ordinal or something else?

Comment: I would guess probably "ordinal", yes.

Comment: yess its "ordinal" @Anentropic

Answer (score 0):

It stands for ASCII code, which is a code for the most general characters, like letters, digits, point, comma, ...

More information can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

From the [python docs for ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord)

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character...  This is the inverse of `chr()`.

So ord() will return the integer that represents a single character that is passed to it.